# spring application context in a set of unittest classes

Tags: spring, junit4, applicationcontext

I have created a couple unittest classes in the same package. All these classes have exactly one testcase and have the same annotation as shown below:

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {TestConfig.class} )

When I run these testcases, I want each testcase be run in its own application context. But it seems all the testcases in the same package share one single application context, be it run from maven command line, or in Eclipse select the package to run as junit.

If I duplicate the TestConfig wiht names like TestConfig1, TestConfig2, etc. and annotate different test class with different TestConfig class, then each test will run in its own context instance.

Is there other elegant method to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of Spring test. Spring test default caches the application context across the tests. This decreases the test execution time.

I dont know about your use case. If u have any where u are dirtying the application context(changing the state of the beans that are managed by springs that is affecting the subsequent tests ) then u can go for annotating the test method with @DirtiesContext. Spring test reloads the context for these methods. See below link how to use DirtiesContext.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching

Use this feature carefully whenever needed only as this may shoot up your test execution time exponentialy.